# Windows swap keyboard mapping of @ (at) symbol and " (quote)

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've recently moved to France from the UK and have a UK QWERTY keyboard, but certain symbols have been swapped such as the at symbol and the double quote. I'm using Windows 7 French version, with the language changed to EN-GB in the system tray.

Is there an easy way to change the keyboard mapping to the UK standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage keyboard layouts through the Control Panel.

Clock, Language, and Region -> Change keyboard or other input methods

[image: Keyboard language dialog]

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick - took me a while to find that, as everything in windows is in French... ;-)